# Use multiple database connections based on user role

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

In my Django project, I would like to restrict the DB access for users based on their respective roles. For example, a user with admin role will have a DB connection with which he can read and write and a normal user will have a read-only database connection. I already tried the 'DATABASE-ROUTERS'.I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: You can revoke permissions from public, then create group roles with permissions that you want them to have and grant those roles to your users. It does not matter what ORM you are using for that.

Comment: I believe you are talking from the perspective of connection handling in PostgreSQL, I have done that part, the problem I have to solve is 'choosing a database connection (among the ones I created) at runtime', or specifically when a request comes in.

Comment: Not really, it is more like PostgreSQL account management. I assumed that your users will log in with individual roles in Postgres. But of course if you have your own login system then you can make those group roles as normal roles and log in with them instead. You can have one basic role that will only have access to users table and check what "permissions role" you should use for secondary connection that will handle everything else, except authentication.